# highcharts display all dates for all points on x-axis

Tags: datetime, highcharts

I have a spline graph with date time on x-axis. i want the date time to be automatic but also display it for all points on the x-axis. Take the demo for example - i want all the points to be display with their dates on the x-axis. how do i do this? the demo is found [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time) . I have not tried anything because i do not know how to, that is why I am asking on here. why it is complaining to not let me post still i do not know why.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions) like in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/z5P8d/

```
 tickPositions:  [Date.UTC(1970,9, 27),Date.UTC(1970,  9, 26),Date.UTC(1970, 11,  1),Date.UTC(1970, 11, 11),Date.UTC(1970, 11, 25), Date.UTC(1971,  0,  8),Date.UTC(1971,  0, 15), Date.UTC(1971,  1,  1),Date.UTC(1971,  1,  8), Date.UTC(1971,  1, 21),Date.UTC(1971,  2, 12), Date.UTC(1971,  2, 25),Date.UTC(1971,  3,  4), Date.UTC(1971,  3,  9),Date.UTC(1971,  3, 13), Date.UTC(1971,  3, 19), Date.UTC(1971,  4, 25),Date.UTC(1971,  4, 31), Date.UTC(1971,  5,  7)  ],
```

Comment: my dates would be dynamic, i will retrieve them through json

Comment: So once you retrieve them, provide them to the tickPositions array.